# the Access problem by no-WWW

Tags: iis-7

my problem looks strange. when I enter www.upitr.com in browsers, it works, but for [upitr.com](http://upitr.com), It works just in FireFox and Safari while it doesn't work in IE and Chrome.
Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: note: that does not work in my firefox 3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can easily test this using nslookup, too:

```
$ nslookup upitr.com     
Server:     8.8.4.4 
Address:    8.8.4.4#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find upitr.com: No answer

$ nslookup www.upitr.com     
Server:     8.8.4.4 
Address:    8.8.4.4#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    www.upitr.com 
Address: 68.71.136.29
```

And yep, some browsers try adding www. if the main domain doesn't resolve.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox and Safari might be adding the `www` automatically if the base address doesn't resolve.

To find out what exactly is going on use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and filter for DNS traffic. This way you would see exactly which DNS queries are generated and what are the responses.